# Map multiple custom domain with on Azure Cloud Service with SSL

Tags: azure, ssl, azure-cloud-services, domain-mapping

We have one Azure Cloud Service (lets call it AB1) on which we have deploy our web application.

My question is how can I map multiple custom domain with AB1 some with SSL and some without SSL.

suppos I want to map...
https://www.abcexample.com
https://www.xyzexample.com
http://www.defexample.com

Comment: Questions: 1) Is there a particular reason why you want to map some custom domains with SSL while some without? 2) I'm assuming you have a single codebase for your Cloud Service which gets deployed just once in AB1.cloudapp,net. Is this correct?

Comment: @GauravMantri:
Answer: 1) We have multiple clients who want to use our application with white labeled URL. Some client has SSL and some has not.
Answer: 2) Yes we have only one code based deployed at AB1.

Comment: What about answer to #2?

Comment: I have answered #2 in above comment.